# SyntaxError: invalid predicate using lxml iterfind

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I am currently struggling with iterating through a XPath expression. I am trying to retrieve all the system-out nodes that contains a substring of "[[SOMETHING|". The issue is that I get the following syntax error that points to the tree.iterfind.

```
    for elem in tree.iterfind('.//system-out[contains(.,"[[SOMETHING|")]'):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2288, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.iterfind
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1588, in lxml.etree._Element.iterfind
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 312, in lxml._elementpath.iterfind
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 295, in lxml._elementpath._build_path_iterator
  File "src/lxml/_elementpath.py", line 237, in lxml._elementpath.prepare_predicate
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

```
tree = etree.parse(test_file)
for elem in tree.iterfind('.//system-out[contains(.,"[[SOMETHING|")]'):
     print("do something")
```

The above is my code. As far as I can see I don't have any syntax error. And I have also tried to test the xpath expression using a free formatter tool, and that seems to work.
I just can't seem to see what is wrong. I have attempted to use the "findall" function provided by lxml but I receive the same error. I have also tried to compile the xpath expression using the etree.XPath function into an attribute, however I received an TypeError that says the following, which makes sense.

```
TypeError: 'lxml.etree.XPath' object is unsliceable
```

Is there something I am missing? Or is just an unsupported expression by the lxml package itself?

Comment: It's complaining that the XPath expression is not valid.

Comment: @Barmar But it seems to work, using this tool: [link](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#before-output) Does lxml expect some kind of different format?

Comment: The `find` methods (`iterfind`, `find`, `findall`, 'findtext`) in both ElementTree and lxml don't support the full XPath 1.0 syntax so the error might just indicate that you have passed in an expression that is too complex to work as an "element path", even if it is a legal XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax lists the supported features, a call to an XPath function (like `contains`) in a predicate is not listed there at all, it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin Honnen explained in the comments, the `find` methods (`iterfind`, `find`, `findall`) in ElementTree and lxml does not support the full XPath 1.0 syntax which explains the `SyntaxError: invalid predicate` error.

I used the `lxml.etree.xpath()` function instead, which does support the XPath 1.0 syntax. Being able to retrieve the text in the XML file I then used the result of the `xpath()` function to iterate over all of the occurrences by using a much simpler XPath expression that `iterfind` can understand.

```
occ = tree.xpath('.//system-out[contains(.,"[[SOMETHING|")]')[0].text
for elem in tree.iterfind(f'.//*[.="{occ}"]'):
     print("do something")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `SOMETHING` instead of `[[SOMETHING|` still can be used and will be a unique enough I'd suggest instead of this
`.//system-out[contains(.,"[[SOMETHING|")]` to use just this:

```py
'.//system-out[contains(.,"SOMETHING")]'
```

So the entire code line will be

```py
for elem in tree.iterfind('.//system-out[contains(.,"SOMETHING")]'):
```

Comment: This still throws the syntax error: invalid predicate: `for elem in tree.iterfind('.//system-out[contains(.,"SOMETHING")]'):`

Comment: Well, maybe this is because methods you are using not supporting such complex methods as mentioned by Martin Honnen